# How to replace column data (which are Indexes of a series) with corresponding Values of a series

Tags: python, pandas

```
prices #This is a Pandas series
Apple 3
Banana 2
Pear 5

df.sales
Apple
Pear
Pear
Banana
```

I want to map the prices in the Series over to df.sales, so that df.sales becomes

```
3
5
5
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
#all non match values are replace to NaN
df['sales'] = df['sales'].map(s)
```

Or:

```
#all non match values are not changed
df['sales'] = df['sales'].replace(s)
```

---

```
#index values have to be unique
s = pd.Series([3,2,5],index=['Apple','Banana','Pear'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales':['Apple','Pear','Pear','Banana', 'Orange']})

df['sales1'] = df['sales'].map(s)
df['sales2'] = df['sales'].replace(s)
print (df)
    sales  sales1  sales2
0   Apple     3.0       3
1    Pear     5.0       5
2    Pear     5.0       5
3  Banana     2.0       2
4  Orange     NaN  Orange
```

Comment: Good one sir :)